# Why do Jewish books use shiny text on the spine?

Tags: history, jewish-books, books-generally, provenance, religious-articles

I have noticed that *sefarim* (Jewish books) tend to use golden-colored shiny text on the spine and cover. Of course, there are some notable exceptions (e.g. books by *Mossad HaRav Kook*), but this seems true of the vast majority, including popular books such as the Artscroll series. Indeed, I've noticed that I can distinguish a shelf laden with *sefarim* from one with secular books at a glance based on whether it shimmers from a distance.

Is there a name for this, and why is it practiced? Has this been in use for a long time, or is it a recent trend? Moreover, was it used in the past for secular books as well?

Example (from [User: Reuvenk](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Reuvenk) / [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/) / [CC-BY-3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)): [image]

Comment: You could ask a similar question about the choice of colour of many sefarim (brownish red, brown, dark blue). Is it not merely a style that has caught on?

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/302/759

Comment: Because it looks nice?

Comment: hukat hagoyim :)

Answer (score 2):

While I'm afraid I will be unable to provide a definitive source I believe that [my hypothesis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/723/899) to answer the question @DoubleAA referenced in his comment is all but certainly applicable here:

> I am not certain but I suspect that it is simply a decorative
> practice. I believe I have seen it done on older, non-Jewish books and
> I assume that the practice has faded in favor of more
> economical/contemporary styles. Jews who buy seforim, on the other
> hand, are a little more inclined for "classic" styles and or more
> interested in a more distinguished graphic design (Goldleaf is not
> common among general books anymore but the rule among seforim).